# Crystal Reports XI not taking parameter from VB6 Program and passing it into stored procedure

Tags: crystal-reports

I did my best to try and explain my problem elsewhere, but so far none has really known anything. This project has just kind of been handed to me. A link to my explanations that I have so far. I can try and provide any further information that's needed: http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/1pqzvi/crystal_reports_xi_not_passing_variables_from_vb6/

Comment: It would be very useful to post your code here. I checked your link out but the formatting of the code on that site is horrible.

Comment: so far the only code im using works. if i put a valid po number thats been created into crystal reports preview it will give me a completed invoice. In ssms if i do the same thing when execute the stored procedure i get the same results. The field that the old report was getting the po number from the vb6 program still populates correctly on the new report. it just doesnt run it through the stored procedure and im confused as to why it would work on one and not the other. the only thing thats changed is the use of the stored procedure. the old report pulled whole tables whereas my stored

Comment: procedure only pulls information i need and stores it in a temp table. The old form didnt pull enough information and didnt join some of the tables i needed to get the correct information for the formulas which is why we went with the stored procedure.

Comment: Have any of the field names maybe changed? I also ready through your code again on the link you provided, and there is an inconsitency here: WHERE "PODetail"."PONumber"=@PoNumber and PODetail.Upc = @UPC ORDER BY "PODetail"."UPC" where the quotes are missing on PODetail.Upc.

Comment: the field names are all the same. basically what i did was took the old report and stripped the tables that it was pulling then set my datasource to my stored procedure and linked the fields to it instead. ive never worked in crystal reports before save for this past week fighting this thing and am pretty new to programming in general so i think it may mostly be errors on my part and im overlooking something small. i did however find this: http://www.kiranreddys.com/knowledgebase/index.php/article/how-to-pass-formula-values-to-a-stored-procedure-i recently and am working on trying it.

Comment: The only reason i mention that link is i noticed that when i add the parPONumber field to my report its listed as a formula field. When i save my report and create an invoice in the VB6 program that field/formula still populates. in selection formulas/reports the ponumber is equal to that formula. the old one passes it to the tables the new one doesnt pass it to the stored procedure. im working on creating a new report to test what they are saying and will post results when i know. Thank you for your responses by the way.

Comment: You're welcome. It's an interesting problem and I hope you get it figured out.

Comment: myself and another more experienced programmer have been fighing this problem for about a week now. once we get this problem solved we should be home free on this project. Neither one of us have experience with crystal so there is the down fall.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does precisely what you are asking for, assuming you have placed the CRViewer control on your form naming it CRViewer1.

Even though you might already understand the code, perhaps a novice VB6 programmer is reading this, so I have added additional comments that explain what is happening.

```
Dim crxApp As New CRAXDDRT.Application 'Instantiate the CR ActiveX component
Dim crxRpt As CRAXDDRT.Report 'This is the report object created by CR

'Open the report definition file.  TheReportName example: MyReport.rpt
Set crxRpt = crxapp.OpenReport(App.Path & "\Reports\" & TheReportName)
'This is how we pass a value as a parameter to the report
'If you have more than one parameter, copy, paste, and edit for ParameterFields(2)
CrxRpt.ParameterFields(1).AddCurrentValue ("Your value here")
'The following assigns the generated report document to the CRViewer1 control and
'waits for the user to close the control
CrViewer1.ReportSource = CrxRpt
CrViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = True
CrViewer1.ViewReport
CrViewer1.Zoom (75)
While CrViewer1.IsBusy
    DoEvents
Wend
CrViewer1.Refresh
```

Comment: @MattDMo, Here I am trying to get enough points for reputation on this site as I had in my request which you removed.  I asked the OP to mark this as an answer, and you downvote me without a comment.  Is my code wrong?  No.  I have been struggling with this site, because people seem more adamant about my politeness (downvotes for saying thank you, for example) than stopping people from asking questions who never mark answers as accepted.  How on earth is a civil, helpful individual supposed to exist in this space?  Come on, man, give a gal a break.

Comment: @MattDMo, So sorry.  I received a message in my inbox saying that you "removed unnecessary request to be marked as answer", and there was a down-arrowhead next to it, so I thought that meant you down-voted it.  I apologize.

Comment: @ToWhomEverDownvotedMyAnswer, please leave a comment why.  My answer is straightforward, and it works.  What is wrong with that?

Comment: Nope - voting is anonymous on all StackExchange sites, as it should be. As a bit of advice though - people know you're trying to get upvoted for answering questions, so it isn't necessary to say so in your text. Probably the reason your answer got downvoted is that it's code only, with no explanations. A really great answer not gives code to help the OP, but **explains** it as well, gives possible alternatives, and otherwise helps the OP "learn to fish" instead of just handing them the answer.

Comment: I don't know VB, so I can't comment on the quality of your code, but [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20873029/edit) your answer could very well earn you upvotes if you make it a really great one.

Comment: @MattDMO, thanks for your help.  Maybe a miracle will happen and it will get upvoted, who knows.  I agree that voting should remain anonymous, but downvoting without an explanation does not help.  You were kind enough to explain.  I thought the original code was so straightforward, but now I understand.  Cheers, mate.

Comment: To whomever down-voted my answer, could you please up-vote it now that I've added more explanation?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes

Comment: @user2948425, did you try my answer?